# clean and build NetBeans error

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I build a project in java using NetBeans it has more than 3000 thousand
    classes (Interfaces/jFrams). Now I want to make a .jar file but when I click 
    on **Clean and Build**, after few minutes it displays an error which is 
    given bellow. I have also increased the memory of the project 
    using property. 
    **Note:** It displays this error only when I want to clean and build it. 
    **It runs perfectly.**

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position$LineMapImpl.build(Position.java:153)
at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Position.makeLineMap(Position.java:77)
at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavaTokenizer.getLineMap
(JavaTokenizer.java:763)
at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Scanner.getLineMap(Scanner.java:127)
at com.sun.tools.javac.parser.JavacParser.parseCompilationUnit
(JavacParser.java:3130)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:628)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parse(JavaCompiler.java:665)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.parseFiles(JavaCompiler.java:950)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1153)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.ant.JavacTask.execute
(JavacTask.java:145)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute
(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
C:\Users\Me\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SCA Test\nbproject\build 
-impl.xml:923: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Shakir\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SCA Test\nbproject\build
-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 11 minutes 37 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kill all jvm processes and start Netbeans again.
Do a clean and build first.
Its possible multiple hot deployments from your project have taken up a lot of space already.

HTH.

Comment: How i can close jvm processes?